# Symfony 2.7.18 throws "Unknown 'truncate' filter" error in prod but not in dev

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am learning Symfony, coming from a Laravel background. So far I have found it to be a bit quirky, to say the least. I just ran into a strange issue and I wanted to know if anyone has seen anything like this.

I use the http://myapp.local/web/app_dev.php route so I can see the dev toolbar and get more verbose error messaging. One thing I noticed is that when I use the prod route: http://myapp.local/web/app.php I get the following error:

```
Unknown "truncate" filter in "Post/post.html.twig" at line 12
```

The offending line is:

```
<p> {{ post.body | truncate(400) }} </p>
```

Why would this line of code work in dev but not prod? I've tried messing with the cache, etc. but nothing seems to work. Neither the app.php nor app_dev.php file has been modified.

Comment: Be sure you are loading the [Text](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/extensions/text.html) extension, even in production

Comment: Try clearing cache on prod envi : php app/console cache:clear --e=prod

Comment: php app/console cache:clear -e=prod solved the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have in your services.yml:

```
services: 
     twig.extension.text:
         class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Text
         tags: 
             - { name: twig.extension }
```